# Why does Typescripts "typeof function" satisfies " extends (...args: any[]) => any" Generic Condition

Tags: typescript

Given the following code:

```js
type Params<F extends (...args: any[]) => any> =
    F extends ((...args: infer A) => any)
    ? A
    : never;

const fn00 = (name: string, age: number, single: boolean) => true

type test07 = Params<typeof fn00>
```

Why does `typeof fn00` satisfy the Generic constraint of `(...args: any[]) => any`.

According to the documentation returns the `typeof` operator only strings of the type under inspection. Basically:

```
"string" | "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"
```

The documentation to typeof is here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#typeof-type-guards

Comment: Because you can pass it any arguments and it returns anything.

Comment: There are two `typeof` operators. There's a _runtime_ `typeof` which does what you say, and a compile-time `typeof` that evaluates to a TypeScript `type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really two `typeof` operators. One is in expressions, and it is the Javascript `typeof` operator. This operator returns as the documentation says one of those possible values.

The second `typeof` operator exists in types and returns (at compile time) the typescript type of a value (variable, class, function etc). The typescript type of `fn00` is `(name: string, age: number, single: boolean) => boolean` and so in the type `type test07 = Params<typeof fn00>`, `typeof fn00` is going to be this type.

If you were to use `typeof` in an expression (ex `const test = typeof fn00`), you would indeed get just `function`

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Reading the typescript docs without prior knowledge of Javascript features is really confusing.